# Visual Studio 2017 Angular 6 shows "Cannot Get /" First Try Only

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.8.3 with .Net Core 2.1 and Angular 6. I used the template to create the project and upgraded it from Angular 5 to 6. It ran as expected. I removed the template code and added my own. As I added more code I started getting the Cannot GET/ message; however, if I go into any .ts file and save it, refresh the browser everything reloads and comes up as expected. No errors  ever show. I can't see any issues.

I have this in Startup

```
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 360);
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:4200");
        }
    });
```

I'm stumped.

Thanks, 
Paul

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok so this is kind of embarrassing but I am leaving this here just in case someone runs into the same problem and can't figure it out.

I had copied a bunch of code over from a prototype project and I left out a file that wasn't obvious. How did I find it? The **Output window** in Visual Studio! None of the other tools showed anything.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Error: ERROR in src/app/models/user-configuration.model.ts(1,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module './functional-ability.model'.
```

So I guess the lesson here is this:

- **Cannot GET /** seems to be telling you that something is missing
- The Visual Studio **Output window** and **Error List** are your buddies in these, and many other situations.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on the same page and I found my problem with ***ng build*** command, You should try that, Probably you find it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The reason was I used '#' in a project path.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had "C#" in my folder path

```
D:\dev\C#\test_project
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also crucial to point out that the problem can be not only in the app.module.js, but in other build-related files too. I found my issue as a missing (and unresolved as a result) scss stylesheet in angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.
you need to do a little thing. Just **remove** the **deleted components** and **declarations** from **app.module.ts**